# display poll questions after buyer place an order in magento

Tags: magento, survey

after buyer completed transaction[or "place an  order"], I want to provide an option 
for "survey" or "poll" about the site .

So I can know about the buyer's satisfaction about our site.

let me know if you have need any clarifications.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can add "survey" on `success.phtml` page.

Go to your theme `/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/checkout > success.phtml` Add your survey functionality on this page.

This pages displays after  successful transaction.

if you have any question feel free to ask.

Comment: hi,

thanks a lot for reply.

What code i have to put in success.phtml.

can you please guide me about code for adding in success.phtml file.

thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Creating a poll ->

    Navigate to “Poll Manager” under “CMS” ->
    Click on “Add new poll” in the top right ->
    Enter “Poll Question”. This will be the question that you’re asking your customers: ie What is the best open source e-commerce solution?
Add this code in you page :

$poll = Mage::getModel('poll/poll')->load('poll ID');
$poll_answers = Mage::getResourceModel('poll/poll_answer_collection')->addPollFilter($this->getPollId())->getItems();

Comment: hi,

thanks a lot for reply.

<?php



$poll = Mage::getModel('poll/poll')->load('poll 2');



$poll_answers = Mage::getResourceModel('poll/poll_answer_collection')->addPollFilter($this->getP‌​ollId())->getItems();



?>

i used this code at the end in success.phtml file, but it did't worked in success page. can not able to see  any polls.

what wrong i did..?...

you can see my success.phtml file here as you said : http://pastebin.com/Xz3Lg6vZ

let me know if you need any clarifications.....

thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of "poll 2" add poll ID which get after creating poll

Answer (score 1):

In success.phtml try following code to display poll.

```
<?php
    $poll = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('poll/activePoll');
    $poll->setPollId(2);
    $poll->setPollTemplate('poll/active.phtml', 'poll');
    $poll->setPollTemplate('poll/result.phtml', 'results');
    echo $poll->toHtml();
?>
```

You can pass desired poll ID in setPollId method.

You can refer full description using following link.

http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-frontend/reusing-magento-poll-on-any-page-or-any-block/

Comment: hi,

thanks a lot for reply.


I got polls in sucess page. as i created 4 polls i called 4 "poll id" in success.phtml page.

so 4 polls are displaying.

but after i voted for 1 poll, it displayed the result as follows:

SHOPPING CART IS EMPTY

You have no items in your shopping cart.

Click here to continue shopping.

but I want to vote for all 4 polls and than it should display the result as follows :

"Thanks for voting".

if you want see demo, you can check here : http://kidsdial.com/

here you can see the code of success.phtml file = http://pastebin.com/CY2eqcpN

thanks in advance